Intersection of a reductive subgroup with a maximal Levi
I met the following concrete problem, of which the answer I am not very sure.
Let $G$ be a connected reductive group over $\mathbb{C}$, identified with its $\mathbb{C}$-points. We fix a maximal torus $T$ of $G$ and a Borel subgroup $B$ containing $T$.
Suppose $P$ is a maximal standard (i.e. containing $B$) parabolic subgroup of $G$, with Levi decomposition $P=MN$ ($N$ the unipotent radical, $M$ a Levi). Let $H$ be a connected reductive subgroup of $G$. Suppose the connected component of $H\cap M$ (is this always connected? I have not yet found a counterexample) is the connected center $Z(M)^\circ$ of $M$.
Then, is it true that the derived subgroup $H_{\mathrm{der}}$ is of rank $1$ (so that must be isomorphic to $\mathrm{SL}_2$ or $\mathrm{PGL}_2$)?
I think $Z(M)^\circ$ should be a maximal torus of $H$, then $Z(G)^\circ\subset Z(M)^\circ$ is of corank one, so that $H$ has semisimple rank one. But I have not written down a clear proof for "$Z(M)^\circ$ is a maximal torus of $H$". Can anybody give some hint? (Or maybe there is a counterexample?) Thanks a lot in advance!
